# Google Developer Console - Cannot Enable APIs

Tags: api, google-api, web-deployment, google-contacts-api

I'd like to preface this by saying: I'm asking this question here because I've found that the customer support for Google to be a convoluted and cascading nightmare of links that get ever more vague.

Problem:

I am trying to enable Google's Contacts API. When I click on the API Manager, as the [documentation describes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en) as the place to enable APIs, I get a message that says, 'Failed to load.'

Nothing else.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?, or have any ideas on what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the error only for the Contacts API? Do you get it only for a particular project or for every project in your Developer Console?

Comment: From the API Manager itself, and it happens on all projects.

Comment: This sounds like a transient problem -- one that may resolve itself in a little whilte.

In almost all cases, you can enable a Google API for a project by:

 1. Going to https://console.developers.google.com/project
 2. Creating or selecting a project
 3. In the project's dashboard, click 'Enable and manage APIs' under 'Use Google APIs'
 4. In the search box at the top of the 'Overview' window, type the name of the API to enable ("Contacts API" in this case).
 5. Click the API name in the search results, then click the "Enable API" button.

Comment: Yes, I've used it before and that is how it should work. Are you able to do this right now?, or do you receive the error as well?

Comment: Even I could not access them(tried logging out and logging in again), then used another computer and I could access them.